# How to obtain a web response exception stream when returned exception is "AggregateException" instead of "WebException"

Tags: c#

I call an internet resource that sends further information in a response stream when it returns "404 Not found".

The first code example, using new asynchronous methods as found in VS 2017, throws an AggregateException, if the call to the resource fails with "404 Not found". Neither the AggregateException nor any InnerException or BaseException contained therein seem to contain a response stream:

1:

```
try
{
    Uri reqUri = new Uri(query.ToString());
    HttpRequestMessage webreq = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, reqUri);
    Task<byte[]> myTask = Task.Run(() => {return myClient.GetByteArrayAsync(webreq.RequestUri); });
}
catch(AggregateException aex)
{
    HttpRequestException hrex = aex.InnerException;
    // neither aex nor hrex contain a response stream
}
```

The second code example, using old methods as already found in VS 2005, throws a WebException, if the call to the resource fails with "404 Not found". The WebException contains a response stream:

2:

```
try
{
    HttpWebResponse webResp;
    HttpWebRequest httpReq;
    httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(query.ToString());
    httpReq.Method = "GET";
    webResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
}
catch(WebException wex)
{
    Stream ReceiveStream = wex.Response.GetResponseStream();
}
```

It is possible to modify code example 1 such that a response stream is obtained from the AggregateException aex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found a solution to my above problem. I amended example 1 to:

```
HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient;
Task<HttpResponseMessage> respTask1;
Task<byte[]> respTask2;
byte[] resultdata;
Uri reqUri = new Uri(query.ToString());
HttpRequestMessage webreq = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, reqUri);
respTask1 = myClient.GetAsync(webreq.RequestUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
//only retrieve the headers at this stage, stream data will be retrieved below
httpmsg = respTask1.Result;
respTask2 = httpmsg.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
//now retrieve the response data in a second task
resultdata = respTask2.Result;
```

This code throws neither an AggregateException nor a HttpRequestException in case of "404 Not Found", so the absence of response stream in either of these is no problem. The "404 Not Found" code is in the response headers (I think it is the StatusCode header) and the associated response stream is in the byte array.